# Authorization in request with Node.js

Tags: node.js, authentication, get, jwt

I have my middleware for authenticating token for hitting a request and I use jsonwebtoken library, it keep returning invalid tokens while I'm sure its not.

This is how I generate my token for login users:

```
const login = async(req, res) => {
  const {username, password} = req.body
    
  User.findOne({
    where:{
      username: username
    }
  }).then(async(user) => {
    if (!user){
      return res.json({
        message: "username or password is wrong!"
      })
    }

    const isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)

    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      return res.json({
        message: "username or password is wrong!"
      })
    }

    const accessToken = jwt.sign({
      id: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      type:"access_token"
    }, process.env.SecretENV, {
      expiresIn: "3m"
    })
    
    return res.status(200).json({
      id: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      accessToken: accessToken,
    })
  })
}
```

below are my auth middleware for the token:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const token = req.header("Authorization")
    console.log(token)
    if (!token) return res.status(403).json({message: "Access Denied"})

    const decoded =  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SecretENV);
    console.log(decoded);
    if(decoded.type == "refresh_tokens"){
      return res.status(403).json({message: "Invalid Token"})
    }
    req.user = decoded
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: error.message
    })
  }
}
```

this is how I call in the router.js:

```
const auth = require('../middleware/auth')
router.get('/api/v0/user', auth, userController.list)
```

after I request to get the user data in postman it returns

> "message": "invalid token"

I have the validation for the tokens if it's type is refresh_tokens is going to be invalid, yet i have not create the refresh tokens part. but, it still returning invalid when I use the token to auth before hit request.